# R- Likelihood function for Cox model with frailty

Tags: r, survival-analysis, gamma-distribution, log-likelihood, cox

I am trying to write an R code for the likelihood function for a cox model with gamma frailty. I know there are packages in R which would do that easily. But I want to write a customized likelihood function for cox model with gamma frailty for my own data rather than using packages.

```
ID  Start_Time  End_Time    Gap_Time    Status  X1  X3  X3
1   0   10  10  1   12  A   150
1   11  90  79  0   16  B   601
2   0   45  45  1   25  A   278
2   46  69  23  1   18  A   895
2   70  90  20  0   23  C   246
3   0   14  14  1   9   A   516
3   15  34  19  1   17  D   385
3   35  61  26  1   10  B   520
3   62  85  23  1   5   C   669
3   86  90  4   0   32  C   553
```

As I would consider myself as an advanced beginner in R and statistics, I need help on this to learn how to do it step by step in R. I was wondering if there is any available codes for that from which I can refer to?

I appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: Do you particularly want to do it from scratch (eg for learning purposes) - because if not, I would first try to find one of the existing packages, work out where the likelihood function there is defined and modify that.  Or at least look at it for inspiration.

Comment: @PeterEllis Even if it is a modified version from a package it would be very very helpful to me. My final purpose is to use general optimization packages like optim to maximize that customized likelihood function.